# Angular and Node.js: Get Call parse Data into object

Tags: node.js, angular, http, get

I am new at Angular and I am trying to create a dashboard for plants. So I want to display data from a MySQL database to my Angular app. To pass the plantdata to Angular I use node.js. I have already managed to present a list of my plants. Now I want to display the details for each plant. But the data isn't displayed, because the object *plant* is undefined. If I try to call directly my node.js server via browser, it works and displays the data as JSON.

I found out, that the data is transferred to my app as JSON correctly and I can display it as a JSON string on my website. I thinks there is a problem to parse the received data from the server into the *plant* object, because I can't get a vaule by using the dot notation like `{{plants.id}}` at the HTML. When I try this I got an error like this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PlantDetailComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)

ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

The method *getPlant* is similar to the method *getPlants* which works and parses the data correctly.

How can I parse the data into the plant object correctly?

Here is my Angular code:

plant.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { Plant } from './plant';

@Injectable()
export class PlantService {
  private plantsUrl = 'api/plants';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPlants(): Observable<Plant[]> {
    return this.http.get<Plant[]>(this.plantsUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getPlants', []))
      );
  }

  getPlant(id: number): Observable<Plant> {
    const url = `${this.plantsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Plant>(url).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Plant>(`getPlant id=${id}`))
    );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

plant-detail.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Plant } from '../plant';
import { PlantService } from '../plant.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plant-detail',
  templateUrl: './plant-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plant-detail.component.css']
})
export class PlantDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  plant: Plant;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private plantService: PlantService,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPlant();

  }

  getPlant(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.plantService.getPlant(id)
      .subscribe(plant => this.plant = plant);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

The component and the service are registered in the app.module. I also registered the HttClientModule.

my Node Server:

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'plant_care',
});
var app = express();

app.get("/api/plants", function(req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM plant', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err)
      res.send(rows);
    else
      console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  });
});

app.get("/api/plants/:id", function(req, res) {
  const requestedID = req.params.id;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM plant WHERE ID = ' + requestedID, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err)
      res.send(rows);
    else
      console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Running...");
});
```

Comment: Can you provide error log? You can check console & network of browser.

Comment: There is no error. It is compiled successfully. The browser also shows no error.Through the network of my browser I can see the response from the node server as json.

Comment: As you're seeing the nodejs server responding properly in the network tab of the browser dev tools, you maybe have an error in displaying the loaded data in your angular template.

Comment: But in the debugger I see that the variable _plant_ is undefined.
I have updated my code and added the HTML view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

My server has sent the data from the MySQL database as an array.

But my function in *plant.service* did not expect an array.
So there were two ways for me to solve the problem. Either I change the service function that it expects an array, or I change the server that it no longer sends a single record in form of an array.

I decided to change the server function:

```
app.get("/api/plants/:id", function(req, res) {
  const requestedID = req.params.id;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM plant WHERE ID = ' + requestedID, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err)
      res.send(rows[0]);
    else
      console.log('Error while performing Query:\n' + err);
  });
});
```